# Can't access mixed (camel) case Java variable names using FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker, camelcasing

I am using FreeMarker (2.3.18) to access Java variables in a custom class. When the variable name has mixed case (camel case) I'm getting an error message saying the variable does not exist.

This is a snippet of my class:

```
 public class Student{

       private String name_last, nameFirst;

       public String getName_last(){
        return name_last;
       }

       public String getNameFirst(){
        return nameFirst;
       }
   }
```

In my FreeMarker template, `${passedInStudent.name_last}` returns the value successfully but  `${passedInStudent.nameFirst}` - returns an error saying

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression
    passedInStudent.nameFirst is undefined on line ...
```

1. Is there a known issue with using camel case variable names in FreeMarker?
2. Is it maybe an issue with this specific version of FreeMarker?
3. Is there a configuration to control it?
4. Is there something else wrong with the way I am accessing these variables?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Note that while it is advisable to remember to ask a question when posting to SO, it is also advisable to limit it to 1 question per post (as opposed to 4).  You might be OK if the questions are closely related, but be aware that 1 q. is more standard.

Comment: That should work. If you're having problems, try dealing the object as a Map (ie add "nameFirst" --> "joe" etc to a hash map and use that instead). that *definitely* works

Comment: See also [Camel case Java variables and freemarker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemarker/forums/forum/2346/topic/4835682).

Answer (score 0):

You code should work. Certainly `nameFirst` is `null`, hence it counts as missing as far as FreeMarker is concerned.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Unfortunately nameFirst is not null. When I change the name of the variable and the getter/setter (i.e. getName_first) everything works as expected. I've played with the different options and it consistently looks like the issue is the upper case... Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Problem solved!

We we're populating the record from JSON code, meaning JSON was trying to use a setter in accordance to the way properties were defined in the JSON notation (upper case, lower case, etc).
Since the setter name didn't comply with the JSON name (i.e. setNameFirst as the setter name vs.  name_first in the JSON) the object was not initialized and the FreeMarker issued an error.

I set a hard coded value in the getter to eliminate the option of the object being null, when I didn't see any error - it let me to the solution.

Thank for listening :)